# Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, kernel, embedded-linux, zynq

I'm trying to work a Linaro Ubuntu desktop on a zynq 7000 through an SD Card. After making the two partitions on the SD card and inserting in the FPGA, I get this message on my host PC (linked to the card through a serial port using UART) :

```
EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 179:2.
devtmpfs: error mounting -2
Freeing unused kernel memory: 244K (c067b000 - c06b8000)
Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.
CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.4.0-g7565292 #1
Hardware name: Xilinx Zynq Platform
[<c0015388>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0011fdc>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<c0011fdc>] (show_stack) from [<c01a8880>] (dump_stack+0x80/0xcc)
[<c01a8880>] (dump_stack) from [<c0092bb0>] (panic+0x84/0x1fc)
[<c0092bb0>] (panic) from [<c046da5c>] (kernel_init+0xb8/0xe4)
[<c046da5c>] (kernel_init) from [<c000f1b8>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x3c)
CPU0: stopping
CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.4.0-g7565292 #1
Hardware name: Xilinx Zynq Platform
[<c0015388>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0011fdc>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<c0011fdc>] (show_stack) from [<c01a8880>] (dump_stack+0x80/0xcc)
[<c01a8880>] (dump_stack) from [<c0013be4>] (ipi_cpu_stop+0x3c/0x6c)
[<c0013be4>] (ipi_cpu_stop) from [<c00142e4>] (handle_IPI+0x5c/0x7c)
[<c00142e4>] (handle_IPI) from [<c00093e0>] (gic_handle_irq+0x74/0x90)
[<c00093e0>] (gic_handle_irq) from [<c0012a94>] (__irq_svc+0x54/0x90)
Exception stack(0xc06b9f38 to 0xc06b9f80)
9f20:                                                       00000000 00000000
9f40: 1f4e0000 dfb95dc0 67b69607 00000000 67dd2149 00000000 dfb95450 00000000
9f60: 00000000 00000000 00000008 c06b9f88 c031d9fc c031da44 60000113 ffffffff
[<c0012a94>] (__irq_svc) from [<c031da44>] (cpuidle_enter_state+0xfc/0x1f4)
[<c031da44>] (cpuidle_enter_state) from [<c00518f8>]  (cpu_startup_entry+0x1a0/0x230)
[<c00518f8>] (cpu_startup_entry) from [<c067bc18>] (start_kernel+0x364/0x3d0)
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.
```

And the VGA-connected monitor does not display anything.
Can someone help me understanding the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you that the system cannot find `init`.

The system could not mount your drive hence the error `devtmpfs: error mounting -2`

Your files might be corrupted or your SD card is not recognized and connected properly.

You might need take a look at your file system.  Make sure that all the folders like `/bin /boot /dev /etc /home /install /lib ...` are all in `/` .  Remove the extra directory if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check the location of init in your filesystem as the error seems to point out that init is not locatable.

Further, the `devtmpfs: error mounting -2` seems to convey that the devtmpfs mounting point is not present in the root partition.

Check whether whether rootfs is available or not in the root partition of card